# how i seed ruby on rails image data and print it on html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to insert image data on seeds.rb and print it on my index page.How it possible?

I tried on seeds.rb.It stores image path but can not find the image and not print it on index page

Comment: you can try using a gem like paperclip to handle your attachments

Comment: If you expect to get any help, you should probably add to your question, (1) what your urls look like, and (2) how you're trying to display on the index page (i.e., your `image_tag`).

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" along with their linked pages. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" and "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" will help too. We need a lot more information and have no idea what you tried.